# (initscripts) Execute a command, if the command does not complete in 10 seconds, run another

Tags: debian, init, posix, start-stop-daemon

On (Debian) Linux I want to:

- Execute a command.
- If the command doesn't complete in 10 seconds, kill it and try another command.

The use-case is:

I have a daemon service which I would like to shut down gracefully.
It can be stopped by sending a TCP command. 
If the TCP command does not return, kill the process using Posix HUP.

start-stop-daemon doesn't seem to do this, anyone got any hints ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also didn't give a medal for the debian people implemented `start-stop-daemon`.

I think, you want to make a workaround about some daemon. There is a tool named `timeout` in the GNU CoreUtils package, which could you help to do this:

```
timeout --kill-after=15 --signal=9 this_is_my_command || this_will_run_on_fail
```

It will run `this_is_my_command`, and if it timeouts, it will kill this with signal 9 (hard kill), and run the command `this_will_run_on_fail`.

I get this information partially from [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43340/how-to-introduce-timeout-for-shell-scripting) question.

Comment: Good find dude!